# Count number of files in end directories using Python

Tags: python, operating-system, filesystems

I have a image dataset archived in tree structure, where the name of different level of folders are the labels of these images, for example

```
/Label1
      /Label2
             /image1
             /image2
      /Label3
             /image3
/Label4
      /image4
      /image5
```

Then how could I count number of images in each **end folder**. In the above example, I want to know how many images are there in folder `/Label1/Label2`, `/Label1/Label3` and `Label4`.

I checked out the function `os.walk()`, but it seems that there is no easy way to count number of files in each individual end folder.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked out the function `os.walk()`, but it seems that there is no easy way to count number of files in each individual end folder.

Sure there is. It's just `len(files)`.

I'm not 100% sure what you meant by "end directory", but if you wanted to skip directories that aren't leaves—that is, that have subdirectories—that's just as easy: `if not dirs`.

Finally, I don't know whether you wanted to print the counts out, store them in a dict with the paths as keys, total them up, or what, but those are all pretty trivial, so here's some code that does all three as examples:

```
total = 0
counts = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if not dirs:
        print(f'{root}: {len(files)}')
        counts[root] = len(files)
        total += len(files)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `os.walk()`:

```
import os
c=0
print(os.getcwd())
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('C:/Windows'):
    for files in filenames:
        c=c+1
print(c)
```

output:

```
125765
>>>
```

If you have multiple file formats in sub-directories, you can use an operator and check jpeg, png, and then increment the counter.